# Always start app with launcher activity in android

Tags: android

My app contains 3 activities . Let's say A,B,C .
A is start up activity.
Now  run app this way - A -> B -> C
Now i press Home key (home screen appears).
Now when i again press app icon to start app , then start with activity C at front.
But i want my app always start with activity A when press app icon on home screen.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

finish the activities B and C during OnPause

```
  onPause(){ finish();}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onPause()
{
  B.this.finish();
  C.this.finish();
}
```

This will remove B and C activity from Activity stack so you will not see activity B and C again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to override the home button

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the home button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
// finish activities here                 
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```